# Which UK visa is applicable?

Tags: indian-citizens

My husband would be on 6 months work visa and I would like to visit him in London for 2-3 months. IN that duration I would like to work from home/service apartment out of London and carry my office laptop. In such scenerios which visa am I applicable to apply being Indian resident.

Comment: Too many variables for the info you have provided. It's a question best put to the Authorising Officer at your husband's sponsor. Close voting in favour of Expats.